# Neo4j query returning more nodes

Tags: java, jpa, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I am working on a java application using Neo4j as DB. MY data model uses a class connected to same class in a type of child-parent relationship.
I have a query to get all children for a certain node, however, since parent and child are same class, my query is returning all nodes including parent node. See code below:

```
@NodeEntity
class A {
    @Id
    private String id;

    @Relationship(type = "PARENT")
    private Parent parent;

    // Constructor, getters, setters, etc.
}

@RelationshipEntity(type = "PARENT")
class Parent {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long relationshipId;

    @StartNode
    private A child;

    @EndNode
    private A parent;
    // Constructor, getters, setters, etc.
}

class Repository { // simplified repository class
    @Query("MATCH(c:A)-[r:PARENT]->(p:A {id: $id}) return c,r,p")
    List<A> getParents(@Param("id") String id);
}
```

If I change query to:

```
class Repository { // simplified repository class
    @Query("MATCH(c:A)-[r:PARENT]->(p:A {id: $id}) return c")
    List<A> getParents(@Param("id") String id);
}
```

it indeed returns only child nodes, but I get null if I do something like a.getParent().

Is there a query I can use to get all children with nested parent?

Comment: I'm not seeing the issue. The way I read the first bit of code, it does exactly what you're asking it to do. It returns the two nodes, that happen to be instances of the same Java class, and the relationship between them. Please help me understand what the concern is.

Comment: @hoyski, if I have a structure like node1 -> node2, so node2 is parent of node 1. Using  first query I get a list with all two nodes, second query returns node1 only, however, doing node1.getParent() return null.

Comment: If I'm following everything correctly then I think the issue is that in your second query you're not returning the PARENT relationship. There's nothing to deserialize so the `parent` member in the `A` instance is null

Comment: Yes, I want to get the parent as well, however I do not want it in same response list (as in first query) because otherwise I will have to do something to indentify which node on that list is the parent.

Comment: It sounds like you need another method in you repository then to retrieve the other `A` node